# search for node using contains in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to search all nodes that start with searchResult1, searchResult2 until searchResult10 in my C# program from an HTML input. here's my code

```
var results = hdoc.DocumentNode
             .Descendants("div")
             .Where(x => x.Attributes.Contains("id") &&
                       x.Attributes["id"].Value.Contains("\"searchResult")).ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
            {
                rawdata[i] = results[i].InnerHtml.Trim();
            }
```

My HTMl looks like this

```
<div id="searchResultTable" class="searchReturnData"> some junk html
<li id="searchResult1" class="searchResult searchResultsData_OFF"> searchResult1 html </li>
<li id="searchResult2" class="searchResult searchResultsData_OFF">searchResult2 html </li>
<li id="searchResult3" class="searchResult searchResultsData_OFF">searchResult3 html </li>
</div>
```

I want to print only searchResult1,searchResult2,searchResult3 html only and not some junk html. How can I do this.

Thanks
Rashmi

Comment: Are you trying to use HTML like XML?  Cause dont.. use HTML Agility Pack instead.

Comment: Tried that too HtmlNodeCollection totNodes = hdoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li[contains(@id='searchResult')]") i get error

Comment: "i get error" tells us absolutely nothing about the problem you're running into. Compile error? Runtime exception? Unexpected behavior? What happened? What did you expect to happen? What have you attempted to fix this already? Please elaborate.

Comment: @tnw, its runtime error. Function 'contains' in '//li[contains(@id='searchResult')]' has an invalid number of arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can use the [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse HTML. you can do something like this

```
         HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
         doc.Load(@"C:\file.html");
         var root = doc.DocumentNode;
         var a_nodes = root.Descendants("li").Where(c=>c.GetAttributeValue("id","")
                       .Contains("searchResult")).ToList()
```